# Can axis2-1.5.1 alone can be used to write and test java web services without Tomcat?

Tags: testing, axis

(3/15/2010) Hi
I am trying to test web services using axis2-1.5.1 (latest version) alone without Tomcat. 
Is it possible? If so, can someone point me how to do that?
Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a web server at any way to test a web application. If you want to ease the development, testing and mocking, consider using an embedded server like [Eclipse Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). You can configure/execute it programmatically.

Comment: Hi Balu 
Thanks for your response. Can you point me to any site/blog that explains how to write, deploy and test a simple webservice using Tomcat/Jetty and AXIS?

Comment: Sorry, no one comes to mind. Just learn each one by one and then do the math.